# Stuck on producing a piechart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pie-chart

```
1         Neutral
2        Positive
3        Positive
4         Neutral
5         Negative
           ...  
Name: Analysis, Length: 63664, dtype: object
```

How can i produce a pie chart for this column above
i have no isea what to do next
i tried finding the percentage myself:

```
pos_tweets = pos_tweets['tweet']
print(f"We have {round((pos_tweets.shape[0]/clean_df.shape[0])*100,1)}% positive tweets")

neg_tweets = clean_df[clean_df.Analysis == 'Negative']
neg_tweets = neg_tweets['tweet']
print(f"We have {round((neg_tweets.shape[0]/clean_df.shape[0])*100,1)}% negative tweets")

neutral_tweets = clean_df[clean_df.Analysis == 'Neutral']
neutral_tweets = neutral_tweets['tweet']
print(f"We have {round((neutral_tweets.shape[0]/clean_df.shape[0])*100,1)}% neutral tweets")
```

And i am stucked on what to do next...

```
pi = clean_df.groupby('Analysis')
labels = ["Positive","Negative","Neutral"]

colors = sns.color_palette('bright')[0:5]

#create pie chart
plt.pie(pi, labels = labels, colors = colors, autopct='%.0f%%')
plt.show()

#i did that and i encounter this error
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2022-07-30 17:50:04+00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` and then `plot.pie`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["Positive", "Negative", "Negative"])
df.value_counts().plot.pie()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i still cannot find my way around it, the above codes does count the number of time each values appear in that column

Comment: Hi @eddie, what exactly doesn't work? And how does your dataframe look like? Is that just one column with Neutral/Positive/Negative values? Or do you have more columns?

Comment: it is just that one column

Comment: @eddie then what doesn't work? How it my example not sufficient?

Comment: it does not iterate through the column to give out the percentage of occurence of each values

Comment: @eddie you'll have to provide more info if you want a solution to your problem.